# Stored procedure inner join

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My first stored procedure (in sql-server). I'm not able to make it work, it raises a warning in a.Id
After reading, and not really understand much, I'm not even sure if I can use this inner join inside a stored procedure.

```
select top 1 b.*, a.*
FROM Bids b
INNER JOIN Auctions a 
ON b.Auction_Id = a.Id
(NOLOCK) WHERE ( a.Ends IS NOT NULL AND a.Starts IS NOT NULL AND a.Starts < @Now AND a.Ends > @Now)
ORDER BY b.CreationTime DESC
```

Actually, I'll need just b.* but I assume I have to retrieve all the fields?.

Thanks

Comment: You can retrieve b.* only. (nolock) hint comes after alias - `Auctions a (nolock)`

Comment: If you don't really understand much, starting with hints (such as `NOLOCK`) is a bad starting point. Also, you say it "raises a warning" - but you haven't given us the text of that warning. Even if it doesn't mean much to you, it may have meaning to those who seek to help you.

Comment: You're right Damien, this one has been solved but will take that into account for the next time. As well as looking at hints more thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the locking hint to this:

```
INNER JOIN Auctions a WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Full query would be:

```
select top 1 b.*, a.*
FROM Bids b
     JOIN Auctions a WITH(NOLOCK) ON b.Auction_Id = a.Id
WHERE ( a.Ends IS NOT NULL
    AND a.Starts IS NOT NULL
    AND a.Starts < @Now
    AND a.Ends > @Now)
ORDER BY b.CreationTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the `(Nolock)` out, or put it after the table name if you need it.

You can use `Select` to select any fields you want from any table in your query.